# Mongodb select all fields group by one field and sort by another field

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

We have collection 'message' with following fields

```
_id |   messageId |  chainId | createOn

1   |       1     |    A     | 155
2   |       2     |    A     | 185
3   |       3     |    A     | 225
4   |       4     |    B     | 226
5   |       5     |    C     | 228
6   |       6     |    B     | 300
```

We want to select all fields of document with following criteria

1. distict by field 'chainId'
2. order(sort) by 'createdOn' in desc order

so, the expected result is

```
_id |   messageId |  chainId | createOn

3   |       3     |    A     | 225
5   |       5     |    C     | 228
6   |       6     |    B     | 300
```

We are using spring-data in our java application. I tried to go with different approaches, nothing helped me so far.
Is it possible to achieve above with single query?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you want is something that can be achieved with the aggregation framework. The basic form of ( which is useful to others ) is:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Group by the grouping key, but keep the valid values
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$chainId",
        "docId": { "$first": "$_id" },
        "messageId": { "$first": "$messageId" },
        "createOn": { "$first": "$createdOn" }
    }},

    // Then sort
    { "$sort": { "createOn": -1 } }

])
```

So that "groups" on the distinct values of "messageId" while taking the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first) boundary values for each of the other fields. Alternately if you want the largest then use [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last) instead, but for either smallest or largest by row it probably makes sense to [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) first, otherwise just use [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/#grp._S_min) and [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max) if the whole row is not important.

See the MongoDB [**`aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) documentation for more information on usage, as well as the driver JavaDocs and SpringData Mongo connector documentation for more usage of the aggregate method and possible helpers.

Answer (score 4):

here is the solution using MongoDB Java Driver

```
    final MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    final DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mstreettest");
    final DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("message");

    final BasicDBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$chainId");
    groupFields.put("docId", new BasicDBObject("$first", "$_id"));
    groupFields.put("messageId", new BasicDBObject("$first", "$messageId"));
    groupFields.put("createOn", new BasicDBObject("$first", "$createdOn"));

    final DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

    final DBObject sortFields = new BasicDBObject("createOn", -1);
    final DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", sortFields);

    final DBObject projectFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0);
    projectFields.put("_id", "$docId");
    projectFields.put("messageId", "$messageId");
    projectFields.put("chainId", "$_id");
    projectFields.put("createOn", "$createOn");
    final DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", projectFields);

    final AggregationOutput aggregate = collection.aggregate(group, sort, project);
```

and the result will be:

```
{ "_id" : 5 , "messageId" : 5 , "createOn" : { "$date" : "2014-04-23T04:45:45.173Z"} , "chainId" : "C"}
{ "_id" : 4 , "messageId" : 4 , "createOn" : { "$date" : "2014-04-23T04:12:25.173Z"} , "chainId" : "B"}
{ "_id" : 1 , "messageId" : 1 , "createOn" : { "$date" : "2014-04-22T08:29:05.173Z"} , "chainId" : "A"}
```

I tried it with SpringData Mongo and it didn't work when I group it by chainId(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C") was the exception

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
final DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
```

with this one:

```
final DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("_id", groupFields);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution using springframework.data.mongodb:

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.group("chainId"),
                Aggregation.sort(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "createdOn"))
              );
AggregationResults<XxxBean> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "collection_name", XxxBean.class);
```