# Sort and distinct Mongodb in Java 3.2

Tags: mongodb-java

I am having 80,000 documents in my mongodb. I am querying these documents using Java driver. I tried to sort my documents based on particular field then applying distinct filter to this result. Sort option works fine but I cant get distinct documents. I have attached my work examples.

```
    Document query = new Document("RetweetCount",-1);
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().sort(query).iterator();
    try{
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        Document dr = (Document) cursor.next();
        String stat = dr.getString("status");
        int retweetcount = dr.getInteger("RetweetCount");
        //Sort works fine. I have to apply distinct here!!! distinct is based on status field
        System.out.println(retweetcount+"--->"+stat);
    }
    }finally{
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you had a look at http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/com/mongodb/operation/DistinctOperation.html if you give me your sample db i can do a little figuring it out

Comment: @Netwon, My db structure is like this {status:x,retweetcount:2},{status:y,retweetcount:5},{status:x,retweetcount:3}. Each time it stores with new status and its retweetcount. I have to get top retweetcount for status but I have duplicate status in my db. I want to get status:x and retweetcount:3, which has highest retweetcount for that status.

Comment: can you send a back up of your collection?

Comment: @Newton, Yep sure, but how do I send my collection to you?

Comment: upload it on google drive or something and share the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this method but it fetches some unrelated fields.[I referred this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494273/mongodb-select-all-fields-group-by-one-field-and-sort-by-another-field)

```
    ArrayList<Document> dd = new ArrayList<Document>();
    //MongoCursor<Document> cursor1 = collection.find().sort(query).iterator();

    Document grouping = new Document("_id","$status");
    grouping.append("text", new Document("$first","$_id"));
    grouping.append("RetweetCount", new Document("$first","$RetweetCount"));
    grouping.append("screen_name", new Document("$first","screen_name") );
    Document group = new Document("$group",grouping);
    System.out.println(group);

    Document sortfields = new Document("RetweetCount",-1);
    Document sort = new Document("$sort",sortfields);

    Document projectfields = new Document("_id",0);
    projectfields.append("_id", "$text");
    projectfields.append("RetweetCount", "$RetweetCount");
    projectfields.append("sn", "$screen_name");
    Document projects = new Document("$project",projectfields);



    AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = collection.aggregate(asList(new Document(group),new Document(sort),new Document(projects)));
    iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
        @Override
        public void apply(final Document document) {
            System.out.println(document.toJson());
        }
    });
```

output:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "576124fafbfb870794452ac6" }, "RetweetCount" : 643, "sn" : "screen_name" }
```

It omits my text field instead it returns with id field. Also my retweet order was not correct. 
This method works fine but result is different.
Could anyone please correct me!!!

Comment: I got the solution.